# Changing hover color of a responsive table

Tags: css, colors, html-table, hover, responsive

I was trying a simple trick of changing hover color of a responsive table but failed.

I tried chaining the CSS but failed.

Do I need to add more CSS tags to make this happen.

Could you please help me to understand what is wrong in my approach.

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
.table-hover thead tr:hover th, .table-hover tbody tr:hover td {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Table</h2>
  <p>The .table-hover class enables a hover state on table rows within a tbody:</p>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It was working fine for me

Comment: Thanks Jayson. Can you confirm if you are able to see red color on hovering or grey color. Actually i want a red color on hover but I am able to see grey color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put style instead of script on the CSS

Here make it:

```
<style>
.table-hover thead tr:hover th, .table-hover tbody tr:hover td {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Yes it was a silly mistake where the required code was put in the script instead of style which is valid for css.

Answer (score 2):

```
`<style>
 .table-hover thead tr:hover th, .table-hover tbody tr:hover td {
background-color: #FF0000;
 }
 </style>`
```

this code make highlight even over table header, this one make highlight only over table body

```
`<style>
 .table-hover tbody tr:hover td {
  background-color: #FF0000;
 }
 </style>`
```